# Failed to list resources error, when adding a new user to Azure Synapse Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I am trying to add users to my synapse workspace and getting a 'Failed to list resources' error. I have 'Synapse Administrator' role privileges. Please help.

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related to not having enough permissions in the Azure Entra (a.k.a. Azure AD) tenant/directory to search for other users. For example, this happens when you are a guest in an Azure Entra tenant instead of being a full member of the tenant ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#compare-member-and-guest-default-permissions)). You should be able to get around that issue by:

1. adding the missing permissions in Azure Entra,
2. OR adding the user by their user ID (GUID for that user).

For example, I see the same error that you get on one of my Synapse workspaces. I'm a guest on the tenant for that workspace. This is what I get when I try to add the user by name or email:

[image: I cannot add user by name or email]

However, I have no problems adding the user by their user ID (GUID for that user):

[image: I can add user by user id]

Answer (score 1):

- Refer this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/732285/synapse-studio-403-unauthorised-even-with-owner-pe.html)  for similar issue

1. Have created a synapse analytics workspace.
2. I have checked access in synapse analytics workspace.
   [image]
3. To give access to users, you need to have Synapse Admin or Synapse Contributor role permissions.
4. Tried to add a user by clicking on Access control in security tab.
   [image]
5. Clicked on **+ADD** for adding user to synapse workspace .
   [image]
6. Able to get users list from active directory.

7.Try to check your access in access control tab . Refer this  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/732285/synapse-studio-403-unauthorised-even-with-owner-pe.html). In this referred document user is also facing similar issue

Comment: It looks like the issue may be something else. I see the same error as @dikokob. I checked my permissions, like you suggested. I'm Owner of the Synapse workspace resource and a Synapse Administrator of the workspace in Synapse Studio. However, I keep getting the same error.